# How do I post publication just submitted on my CV?

Tags: publications, thesis, cv

I have submitted my publication to a conference awaiting review. I was wondering how do I mention it on my CV, and precisely what the format is.

I completed my undergrad in CS and this is my thesis work. Want to prepare my CV for MS/Ph.D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to put a section in the CV "Work in Progress", list the title as usual and add (submitted for conference). You can name the conference or not.

Adding it to "Publications" could be confusing to some, but if marked with (submitted...) then it is probably clear enough though probably best to put it elsewhere.

It is a short term issue and will change when you get accepted (or not). If not accepted, it is still in progress.

My own view is that having work in progress is a positive thing for most academic applications.